# Unable to pass a foreignkey field to frontend

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

Good morning colleagues. I have a react app with a database with foreignkey fields. I have been able to successfully call the fields without foreignkey data but unable to call the foreignkey fields. My database for example has student table which has a foreignkey reference to stream table. How do I get the stream.name on the frontend. I tried {student.stream.name } but did not work.

```
<table className="layout">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Adm No</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Stream</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {students.map(student => (
                        <tr key={student.id}>
                            <td>{student.student_id}</td>
                            <td>{student.stream.name}</td>
                            <td>Edit</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}


                </tbody>
            </table>


const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
const getStudents = async () => {
    
        const student_data = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/students");
        const Students = await student_data.json();
        setStudents(Students)
    

useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "LLR | Students";
    getStudents();
}, [])
}
```

Comment: react doesn't have to do anything with foreign keys on the server, it depends on the structure of data coming from the server .... what is the data from server can you add a sample one ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What does it mean , data from the server? How do I get that?? I am able to print out { student.name} but not the FK stream.

Comment: I mean what does this log `Students` after fetch call ?

Comment: A dictionary with data like {id: 799, name: 'Peter Okoth', year: '2023', student_id: '101', graduated: false, …}
2
: 
{id: 800, name: 'Moses Pins', year: '2023', student_id: '102', graduated: false, …}
3
: 
{id: 801, name: 'James Oluoch', year: '2023', student_id: '103', graduated: false, …}
4
: 
{id: 803, name: 'Catherine Akinyi', year: '2019', student_id: '645', graduated: false, …}
5
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)